# QGIS raster no data value changed to -inf when viewing at smaller scale

Tags: qgis, raster, color-ramp, colormap

I have a raster with some no-data cells.

I want to visualise raster values using a colour map and set the no data values to transparent.  I am attempting to do this using the transparency tab in the layer properties dialogue.

This all went well when I am viewing a small section of the raster:

[image]

However, when I zoom out the no data pixels become visible and the identify tool says the value is now -inf.

[image]

There seems to be a trigger point at which this happens, for all larger scales the no data values are left transparent and for all smaller scales I get this strange -inf thing.

Why does this happen and how can I stop it?

This is only the 3rd time I have used QGIS so apologies if this is a well known thing that is easily solvable - I couldn't seem to find a similar question.

Due to workplace limitations I am forced to use QGIS 2.2.0-Valmiera.

The raster is a .tif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't seem to replicate your issue. I tested it with a 1:50m global raster and the `no data` values seem to stay transparent throughout the varying scales. Perhaps you can try another method which is to convert your `no data` values to an integer (i.e. `0`). You can do this by:

1. Reprojecting your raster and setting the **No data values** parameter to blank:

   [image: Example raster]

   [image: Warp]
2. The `no data` values should show as `0`:

   [image: Warped raster]
3. Then go to *Layer Properties > Transparency > No data value* and enter 0. Hopefully when you scale, the transparency will remain.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the response - I am still getting the same issues after implementing your solution but I don't get the same error with other raster data I tested.  The raster is derived from vector data so I am going to go back to the beginning and start again to see if I can resolve.

Comment: @ASeaton - Most welcome, hope you can resolve the issue :)